# Why won't AngularJS get invoked in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 in IE11?

Tags: angularjs, html, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I set up a ribbon button to call an html page from my webresources.  I add an example.html page with this code into webresources (taken from W3 schools):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">    </script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here">       </p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The example.html page will come up when clicked, but angularJS isn't being invoked for whatever reason, and {{brackets}} are still displayed as opposed to the angular variables and functions they represent.  The exact same code definitely works in other html compilers I've plugged it into, why is this not working in Dynamics CRM, and how can I get angular to work with the html webresource pages I call?

**Additional Info/Edit:** https vs http has been suggested and has no bearing; actual page with angular.js script in webresource is also having same problem.  Found out that this is only a problem in IE, specifically using IE11.  Works as intended in Chrome and Firefox, but IE is what's supposed to be supported.

Comment: Is it because you don't have any JavaScript code that can bootstrap your app???

Comment: If ng-app is in the html or body tags (in this case the body) it should automatically bootstrap.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MS Dynamics CRM, but does it run under https? If so, you probably need to reference the https CDN because the http reference is likely getting blocked.

Comment: I've tried https call, and also have uploaded angular file to webresources and referenced that, and it's still not invoked.  Other js will execute, so it's not javascript that's blocked.  I'm thinking it's more with MS Dynamics than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!  It works in Chrome/Firefox, which is great, but IE is our main customer base, so it's more of an IE issue than a Dynamics or JS issue. It's forced in doc-mode 5 via intranet compatibility settings, so I have to find a way to get it updated.

Fixed that by plugging this into the IIS web-config, so now everything works as expected.  As a bonus, it's speeding up the loading time of CRM navigation by a lot for everyone as well!

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <clear />
  <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

**Addendum**

It's better with IIS 7 to add an 'X-UA-Compatible' tag in the http response headers options for your sites rather than manipulate the web config directly.

ALSO another part of the problem in IE and Dynamics CRM, is that after adding that tag, you're restricted to uploading html files directly for your web resources.  If you upload one and try to make a simple change through the text editor, Dynamics itself will add its own meta 'x-ua-compatible ie=5.0000' tag that superimposes over your IIS changes, but this is ONLY if you go into text editor after the fact, so simple changes will have to be made to your html file locally and uploaded again.

Comment: Why didn't you just add the proper meta tag to the head-section of your HTML page? I doubt whether your IIS-solution is supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Tried that before the IIS solution via the text editor, which had I realized at the time was the problem and likes to act weird, wouldn't have done so.  Whenever you want to make a simple change to one of your webresource html pages via text editor, it wants to kick in and superimpose its own code.  <!DOCTYPE html> for example to let the browser expect an html5 page, gets IMMEDIATELY overwritten just by opening up the text editor, and gets deleted.  Meta tag does same thing through editor.  It's best just to upload page, and overwrite with another upload.

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with IE opening the HTML web resource as using Document Mode as IE7 standards. IE reports this message in the console if you want to see it. I added the following to my web resource and it fixed the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- You don't have a head tag (though most browsers probably handle this fine)
- The script you're referencing is http instead of https (the real problem)

This works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="">
        <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
        <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately.  I should have mentioned that I also have even uploaded an angular file to webresources and have called it internally, and it still doesn't invoke.  Other js files will, so it's not javascript.  Are you doing it from Microsoft Dynamics?  Is there something with Dynamics that prevents it from being compatible with angular, internally?